# Is $\partial \Omega$ a closed parametrized $C^1$ regular curve?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded, open, connected subset of $R^2$ such that its boundary $\partial \Omega$ is of class $C^1$.

Using the definition in the appendix of Evans - Partial Differential Equations,
we know that for each point $x^0 \in \partial \Omega$ there is $r>0$ and a $C^1$ function $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, upon relabeling and reorienting the coordinate axes if necessary, we have

$$
\Omega \cap B(x^0, r) = \{x \in B(x^0,r): x_2>\gamma(x_1)\}.
$$

Does this imply that $\partial \Omega$ is a closed parametrized $C^1$ regular curve?
More precisely, can write $\partial \Omega = \gamma([a,b])$ for some $C^1$ function $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\gamma'(t) \neq 0 $ for every $t \in [a,b]$ and $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$?

I was thinking that, since $\partial \Omega$ is compact, we could cover it with a finite number of balls, and inside each of them we have a local parametrization.
We could then glue together the various parametrizations to obtain a global one.
But I think that this would only give us a continuous $\gamma$, not $C^1$ in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts are OK: you just have to keep in mind the hypotheses on $\partial \Omega$ being of class $C^1$. You can require your local parametrizations to be arc length parametrizations so that the gluing of the derivative becomes easier.

Edit regarding Mason's comment: of course I was assuming $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the result is true right? Since by parametrizing with arc length I should not have any gluing problem.

Comment: @user3669039 I don't think you will succeed if $\Omega$ is not connected.  consider $\Omega$ to be the union of two disjoint closed disks.

Comment: @Mason You are right. I had in mind a connected $\Omega$. I will correct the question.